# Can I stop the location update until the distance reached?

Tags: android, android-location

```
             LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

             LocationListener ll = new mylocationlistener();


               lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, ????, 20, ll);
```

1.if the minDistance (20m)only be applied, what minTime parameter should I input? 0, -1 or 100000000?

2.By the way, I want to prompt user already reached the 20 m distance from original place, but the request update at once when program start and call the location changed function can I ignore the  location changed function until the the distance reached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (untested, but based on [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html)):

```
final LocationManager locationManager =  LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
class implements LocationListener {
    Location storedLocation;
    public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {
        if (storedLocation.equals(null)) {
            storedLocation = newLocation;
        }
        if ((newLocation.distanceTo(storedLocation) > 20.0) { 
            locationManager.removeUpdates(self);   
            return;
        }
        storedLocation = newLocation;
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { }
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { }
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { }
}
```

Comment: some error from eclipse: LocationListener must be declare a abstract class, how to fix it ?

Comment: fixed! Thanks you very much hd1, but not yet tested.

Comment: I just test the code, but the apps start show no any UI at all and final error and close. the following is the partial code, pls have a look! thanks

Comment: package my.project;


@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi" })
public class MyiHome extends Activity { 

 LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  LocationListener ll = new mylocationlistener();
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
          lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000000, 20, ll);
 }
  });

Comment: class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener {   
   Location storedLocation;
     public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {
         if (storedLocation.equals(null)) {
             storedLocation = newLocation;
         }
         if (newLocation.distanceTo(storedLocation) > 20.0) { 
          SetNoitify(); 
             lm.removeUpdates(this);   
             return;
         }
         storedLocation = newLocation;
     }